# Is it possible to bundle SVG symbology in Geopackage or any QGIS single-file vector format?

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I read that the Geopackage format should support attaching a custom SVG symbology in the file.

Does it already work?

If yes, how can I do this?

No matter if GUI or CLI if it works.

Default point symbols are not enough and advising all the users to install additional ones complicates the situation.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but in 3.0.2 and above you can use an svg hosted on a site like github, and qgis will download it when loading the project

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my problem as we use several special plugin which only work in the LTR version.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and recentrly I have found that is a question of discussion ina OGC. "Implication of Geopackage Symbology". At present I only Could save my symbology in spatialite as SLD, I think you can do the same with Geopackage but I haven't tried the same with SVG data, but I think it is possible.

Comment: Yesss we can: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354445/read-and-write-svg-from-geopackage-with-qgis/381416#381416