# Read (and write) SVG from Geopackage with QGIS

Tags: qgis, svg, geopackage

There is the possibility to save the style of a layer in a geopackage:

`Layer.saveStyleToDatabase`

This style can be read by QGIS without additional code.
But is there a way for QGIS to read SVG symbols from a gpkg?

I could write the SVG by code, but **reading should be done without additional code**.

Comment: Do you know https://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.4-LTR/#svg-files-can-be-embedded-projects-symbols ?

Comment: Which version QGIS are you using?

Comment: @etrimaille:
I didn't know it yet. Would be a partial solution, but one would have to deliver an additional (proprietary) file for the GeoPackage.

Comment: @ MortenSickel:
The version is not so important. I am looking for a way to exchange data with others with little effort

Comment: The version is always important. I see many people working with QGIS 2 (not even 2.18), QGIS 3.4.0... nowadays! I'm giving you an answer using QGIS 3.4, maybe you are not using it? How can I guess?And in your question, you are mentioning only SVG, not additional proprietary data.

Comment: I am looking for a future-proof solution. So if this only works from the latest version, this is also a solution.:-)

All data in one file (GPKG) would be optimal for me.

Comment: @etrimaille:
That seems to be the solution. The SVG is not only embedded in the project file, but also in the GeoPackage.
Now I just have to find / create the right code.

Answer (score 6):

I was very interested by myself, to find out how we can package a QGIS project with all external dependencies inside a GeoPackage database. With the help of the "indispensible" expression editor, it's possible to reference SVGs/images stored in a BLOB column and base64 encode on-the-fly.

1. Create a GPKG layer (i.e. "svg") with 2 columns (name:text,image:binary[blob])

[image]

2. Store your SVG images in the layer "svg" (click on the "..." button to embed the SVG):

[image]

3. Reference the SVG symbols in your vector layer (i.e. table "locations", column "type")

[image]

4. Use SVG Marker styling with the following expression to display your SVG symbols

> 'base64:'|| to_base64(attribute(get_feature(
> 'svg','name',"type"),'image'))

[image]

5. **Praise the Qt developer**, who has added support for inline SVGs and inline images!

[image]

Comment: To be honest, Base64 encoding is not really necessary. See my answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374223/using-embedded-svg-symbol-in-multiple-layers