# Storing GDAL VRT sources inside QGIS project files (.qgs, .qgz, .gpkg)?

Tags: qgis, gdal, vrt

After I managed to store SVG symbols in Geopackage BLOBs ([Read (and write) SVG from Geopackage with QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354445/read-and-write-svg-from-geopackage-with-qgis/381416#381416)) another idea was growing in my mind: Maybe we can store simple GDAL VRT sources in GPKG BLOBs or *.qgz files, to bind these datasources to a QGIS project?

Here's a minimal VRT which shows the city of Vienna clipped from a public WMTS (https://basemap.at):

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="293885" rasterYSize="227105" subClass="VRTWarpedDataset">
  <SRS dataAxisToSRSAxisMapping="1,2">EPSG:3857</SRS>
  <GeoTransform>  1.8013609905169420e+06,  1.4929107087160037e-01,  0.0000000000000000e+00,  6.1606686197213698e+06,  0.0000000000000000e+00, -1.4929107087160004e-01</GeoTransform>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1" subClass="VRTWarpedRasterBand">
    <ColorInterp>Red</ColorInterp>
  </VRTRasterBand>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="2" subClass="VRTWarpedRasterBand">
    <ColorInterp>Green</ColorInterp>
  </VRTRasterBand>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="3" subClass="VRTWarpedRasterBand">
    <ColorInterp>Blue</ColorInterp>
  </VRTRasterBand>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="4" subClass="VRTWarpedRasterBand">
    <ColorInterp>Alpha</ColorInterp>
  </VRTRasterBand>
  <BlockXSize>512</BlockXSize>
  <BlockYSize>128</BlockYSize>
  <GDALWarpOptions>
    <SourceDataset relativeToVRT="0">WMTS:https://www.basemap.at/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml,layer=bmaporthofoto30cm</SourceDataset>
    <Transformer>
      <ApproxTransformer>
        <MaxError>0.125</MaxError>
        <BaseTransformer>
          <GenImgProjTransformer>
            <SrcGeoTransform>977649.895640023053,0.149291070871599985,0,6281289.98263385892,0,-0.149291070871599985</SrcGeoTransform>
            <SrcInvGeoTransform>-6548616.00182950962,6.69832424780491387,0,42074116.9981704801,0,-6.69832424780491387</SrcInvGeoTransform>
            <DstGeoTransform>1801360.99051694199,0.149291070871600373,0,6160668.61972136982,0,-0.14929107087160004</DstGeoTransform>
            <DstInvGeoTransform>-12066100.0018294789,6.6983242478048961,0,41266155.9981704652,0,-6.6983242478049112</DstInvGeoTransform>
          </GenImgProjTransformer>
        </BaseTransformer>
      </ApproxTransformer>
    </Transformer>
    <BandList>
      <BandMapping src="1" dst="1" />
      <BandMapping src="2" dst="2" />
      <BandMapping src="3" dst="3" />
    </BandList>
    <SrcAlphaBand>4</SrcAlphaBand>
    <DstAlphaBand>4</DstAlphaBand>
    <Cutline>MULTIPOLYGON (((5501234.2650394 1052508.13225313,5501234.2650394 791668.70254492,5834964.1589386 791668.70254492,5834964.1589386 1052508.13225313,5501234.2650394 1052508.13225313)))</Cutline>
  </GDALWarpOptions>
</VRTDataset>
```

[image]

We could store the VRT file in a QGIS *.QGZ project file and retrieve it via /VSIZIP/, but unfortunately it will be deleted after a project save. (Maybe the core devs could define a QGZ folder where we can store some custom data which won't get lost?)

Geopackage BLOBs are no option either, because I couldn't find a way to open a data stream (i.e. base64 encoded) as VRT data source. It's possible to retrieve data from BLOBs using Python and open it in QGIS from a temp file, but I would prefer a more direct solution.

GDAL has so many Virtual File System handlers, maybe we could use VSIMEM or VSISTDIN to read the data from a Geopackage BLOB.

Does anyone have a brilliant idea to solve this tricky task without using too much Python code?

(@Even Rouault ... something for you?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As so often the answer is so near!

We can easily enter/copy the content of the VRT file instead of selecting it (QGIS 3.16.3. Windows 10). All double quotes need to be replaced by single quotes.

QGIS is and remains a mystery to me with all its hidden features!

[image]

If we use the wonderful *changeDataSource* Plugin, we don't even need to replace all double quotes and can leave the formatting as it is:
[image]

And, best of all, it's not limited to *WMTS* URIs. We can use *GDAL XML* description files as well (i.e. *TMS* sources):

```
gdalwarp -r Lanczos -s_srs EPSG:3857 -t_srs EPSG:31256 -te -10867 330137 17813 350209 -of VRT "<GDAL_WMS><Service name=\"TMS\"><ServerUrl>https://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png</ServerUrl></Service><DataWindow><UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX><UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY><LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX><LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY><TileLevel>18</TileLevel><TileCountX>1</TileCountX><TileCountY>1</TileCountY><YOrigin>top</YOrigin></DataWindow><Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection><BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX><BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY><BandsCount>3</BandsCount><UserAgent>QGIS 3.16.3</UserAgent><Cache /></GDAL_WMS>" vienna_osm.vrt
```

Comment: Hi @christoph! I have follow your advice, but in my case I think that I can't upload my .vrt file into my Qgis project because this line maybe is wrong: <VRTDataset rasterXSize='0' rasterYSize='0'>. Thanks in advance?