# How to cut Google map (OSM) using polygon? in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, google-maps

In QGIS, I would like to use polygon and open street map (google satellite) as "Clip raster by mask layer" to obtain a Google image in the form of polygon.

[image]

However, if you use the Clip raster by mask layer function,
'The following layers were not correctly generated.'

When a message comes out, the desired result is not produced.

Please tell me another good way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of clipping the area by polygon, you can use inverted polygon symbology to mask the area outside the polygon. You can refer to this answer on how to apply inverted polygon:

[Inverted filling of polygon in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255259/inverted-filling-of-polygon-in-qgis)

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to clip WMTS/WMS layers because you like to create small vector PDFs where masking the area is no option, you could use gdalwarp to produce clipped virtual rasters (VRT):

[QGIS Data Frame Clipping for Basemaps](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315637/qgis-data-frame-clipping-for-basemaps/417363#417363)

[Storing GDAL VRT sources inside QGIS project files (.qgs, .qgz, .gpkg)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383421/storing-gdal-vrt-sources-inside-qgis-project-files-qgs-qgz-gpkg)