# QGIS WMS clipping issue

Tags: qgis, wms, clip

I'm using QGIS 3.22.5 Version Białowieża and I am having troubles in clipping a WMS raster with level curves. When I use the function for clipping rasters by polygon (draw area on map) or by a layer mask, the following error message occurs:

```
ERROR 4: `contextualWMSLegend=0&crs=EPSG:32633&dpiMode=7&featureCount=10&format=image/png&layers=CB.IGM25000.32&layers=CB.IGM25000.33&styles&styles&url=http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map%3D/ms_ogc/WMS_v1.3/raster/IGM_25000.map' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
The process resulted in error 1
Execution completed in 0.30 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users/Tommaso/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_aHllSD/fa7a86805d8a443f92ed9a8faa03f765/OUTPUT.tif'}

Load layer
The following layers were not created correctly•
 C:/Users/Tommaso/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_aHllSD/fa7a86805d8a443f92ed9a8faa03f765/OUTPUT.tif
```

Even by trying to save smaller areas, the clipping process does not work.
I also tried to save the layer as GeoTiff but it saves a file map which is shown without any level curves.

An alternative solution could be downloading different maps of the area related to the municipalities. However, there are about 30 municipalities in the area and it might take me too much effort.

Comment: Instead of clipping the WMS by a polygon, you can use the `Inverted Filling of a Polygon`. Check the answer in [How to cut Google map (OSM) using polygon? in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/427863/63384).

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.